# Bad Message 414 reason: URI Too Long

Tags: community, api

I have Executed my code in anonymous window in developer console. here i am converting string to base64Decode. i am getting this error:

> Line: NaN, Column: undefined
>   Response to EXEC was : Bad Message 414 reason: URI Too Long
>   . HTTP CODE[414]

I have newly started working on API's Please Help me to resolve this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiving server is rejecting your URL saying it is too long. When you need to send large amounts of data, you have to use a HTTP POST request and not a HTTP GET which is subject to length restrictions (of no more than a few thousand characters).

Answer (score 8):

You can save the anonymous apex into a file and run it via the Salesforce CLI. Sample command:

```
sfdx force:apex:execute -f "C:\temp\MyApexScript.apex" > result.log
```

Comment: This should have been accepted as the correct answer. There is no way in the Anonymous Apex window to use POST instead of GET, as the answer from @Keith C suggested

Comment: This is the correct answer - thank you!